# Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'String?'

Tags: swift, switch-statement, skphysicsbody

I have a simple switch-statement that is not that simple.

```
switch(bubble?.name){ //bubble is SKPhysicsBody
    case "largeBubble": // <= error
        newBubbleSize = "medium"
        break;
    default:
        newBubbleSize = "large"
        break;
}
```

Here I get error that I mentioned in title `Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'String?'`. And I have no clue why it is a problem that one of them is an optional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html), `bubble?.name` has type `String?`. You have a few options:

- Use `"largeBubble"?` in your `case` expression (Swift 2+ only).
- Check for nil before doing your `switch`, so the switch argument will be a `String` instead of `String?`.
- Use `bubble!.name` (or `bubble.name` if it's a `SKPhysicsBody!`) if you are ***absolutely sure*** that it won't be nil

Comment: Option #4: `switch(bubble?.name ?? "unknown") { ... }`.

Comment: Sure, but then you will be doing an unnecessary comparison with the string "unknown" in some cases :)  Of course, it's probably so fast that it doesn't matter...

Comment: `bubble!.name` didn't work - well, only in combination with `some()`. Thought that's why there's always a default as well ... if name is not set.

Comment: @Jurik exactly what type is `bubble`? (`SKPhysicsBody` or `SKPhysicsBody?` or perhaps `!`)

Comment: It's `bodyA` or `bodyB` from `SKPhysicsContact`.

Comment: `bodyA` and `bodyB` are both `SKPhysicsNode!`. I am not 100% sure, but I suspect these are really never nil, so it's safe to just use `bubble.name`. That is the solution I would recommend.

Answer (score 3):

As @jtbandes said, the problem is the result of `bubble?.name` having type `String?`. An alternative solution, to the ones given, is to override the `~=` operator to take a `String?` and `String` as arguments, for example:

```
func ~= (lhs: String, rhs: String?) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs
}
```

Or, to make it more generic:

```
func ~= <T: Equatable>(lhs: T, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs
}
```

Comment: `Equatable` would be sufficient :)

Answer (score 1):

“Values are never implicitly converted to another type. If you need to convert a value to a different type, explicitly make an instance of the desired type.”

```
“let label = "The width is "
let width = 94
let widthLabel = label + String(width)”
```

Here width is an Integer type it has been converted to String by String(Int) function

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.0 (sender: UIButton) then ! for the switch string works.

```
let operation = sender.currentTitle!
```

In Swift 2.0, (sender: **AnyObject**) then !! for the switch string works.

```
let operation = sender.currentTitle!!
```

the mistake which i made is using AnyObject instead of UIButton.

```
@IBAction func operate(sender: AnyObject) {
        let operation = sender.currentTitle!!

        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypeingNumber{
            enter()
        }

        switch operation{
            case "×":
                if operandStack.count >= 2{
                    displayValue = operandStack.removeLast() * operandStack.removeLast()
                }

                break
//            case "÷":
//                break
//            case "+":
//                break
//            case "−":
//                break
           default:
                break
        }

    }
```